# How can I create a WMS-Service hyperlink to a pdf-file?

Tags: qgis, wms

I like to create a WMS-Service with QGIS.
I want to have a link in the table of the WMS-Service where I can click on and a pdf-file opens.
I know the normal way how to hyperlink a pdf (layer properties and actions), but that doesn´t work when I use the WMS-Service.
Does anybody understand my problem and can help me?

Comment: Hi Maria, Did you come up with any answer to this?